# How can I compress a folder into multiple zip files?

Tags: zip

I'm on mac osx.

1.
Is there any tool to compress a folder into multiple zip files ?

2.
Is there any tool to split a compressed zip file into smaller zip files (to open individually later)?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use the -s switch on the zip command in terminal. So if your folder was called FolderName

```
zip -r -s 64 archive.zip FolderName/
```

64 is the size of the split (in this case 64Mb).

```
Use -s to set the split size and create a split archive.  
The size is  given  as  a  number  followed optionally  by  one  
of  k (kB), m (MB), g (GB), or t (TB) (the default is m). [1]
```

Use zipsplit to split a zip file in to multiple smaller zipfiles.  Use the -n switch to set the size of the splits.

[1] http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/zip.1.html

Comment: @RobZolkos I've done what you suggest and I have a small archive.zip (7mb) and the segments (64mb each). However, I cannot unzip the content, I'm running unzip unix archive.zip but I get "bad zipfile offset (lseek)". Furthermore, I need to extract them in Windows environment as well, and there I only have Windows 7 extractor I guess.

Comment: you just need to run unzip archive.zip   I'm just checking windows now.

Comment: @RobZolkos I've already tried and I added to the question the error I get.

Comment: I just tested it on a folder and it worked fine.  Both zipping and unzipping.  Make sure to unzip in a different folder than the original source.  

On Windows it doesn't unzip.  However a freeware unzip program 7Zip http://www.7-zip.org/   can unzip them without a problem.

Comment: @RobZolkos I get "unsupported compression method" error, do you think the issue is with at extraction step or compression step?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with compression.  Is what you're compressing just standard files?

Comment: @RobZolkos The split seemed successful but I couldn't get unzip to work (or even Archive Utility).

Comment: The link in the answer reference no longer works. I found the following reference: http://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/how-to-create-a-split-zipped-archive-from-mac-os-x-terminal/

Comment: For MACOS 11.0, I have to type "zip -r -s 1024m archive.zip FolderName/"

Answer (score 6):

I just found [Keka](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/32512/keka), maybe it can interest you, and it's free.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.